# How to get the index of FOREACH iterations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Within a FOREACH statement [e.g. day in range(dayX, dayY)] is there an easy way to find out the index of the iteration ?

Comment: your question is not clear? please provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Here is an example query that creates 8 `Day` nodes that contain an index and day:

```
WITH 5 AS day1, 12 AS day2
FOREACH (i IN RANGE(0, day2-day1) | 
         CREATE (:Day { index: i, day: day1+i }));
```

This query prints out the resulting nodes:

```
MATCH (d:Day)
RETURN d
ORDER BY d.index;
```

and here is an example result:

```
+--------------------------+
| d                        |
+--------------------------+
| Node[54]{day:5,index:0}  |
| Node[55]{day:6,index:1}  |
| Node[56]{day:7,index:2}  |
| Node[57]{day:8,index:3}  |
| Node[58]{day:9,index:4}  |
| Node[59]{day:10,index:5} |
| Node[60]{day:11,index:6} |
| Node[61]{day:12,index:7} |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`FOREACH` does not yield the index during iteration. If you want the index you can use a combination of `range` and `UNWIND` like this:

```
WITH ["some", "array", "of", "things"] AS things
UNWIND range(0,size(things)-2) AS i
// Do something for each element in the array. In this case connect two Things
MERGE (t1:Thing {name:things[i]})-[:RELATED_TO]->(t2:Thing {name:things[i+1]})
```

This example iterates a counter `i` over which you can use to access the item at index `i` in the array.